# Button difference in Chrome and IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, internet-explorer-9

So I have a site - on the Input Customer/Save Customer I have some buttons - they display correctly in IE 9 but not in Chrome (the functionality works fine in both) - its just for the appearence that I want to get it looking right in both.

So this is how it should look (IE 9)

[image]

And this is how it looks in Chrome (incorrect)

[image]

I have been trying different stuff in the source below - but havenet got it working in both Chrome and IE yet so maybe someone can spot something I'm missing.

```
                        <div class="PanelPadd" style="margin-top: 10px; text-align: right; padding: 5px; height:25px;">
                            <div id="Div8" style="text-align: right; float: right;">
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td valign="middle" style="padding-right: 5px;">
                                            <a id="FindCorrAddress" href="javascript:pageSMCustomerCreate.doRequest(2)">Find Addresses</a></td>
                                        <td valign="middle" style="padding-right: 5px;">
                                            <a id="ClearCAddress" href="javascript:pageSMCustomerCreate.doClearCAddress()">Clear</a></td>
                                        <td valign="middle" style="padding-right: 5px;">
                                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton4" ImageUrl="./images/buttons/SaveCustomer.gif" runat="server"
                                                OnClick="OnSaveCustomer" /></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

There is nothing special done in any style sheet with the Class PanelPadd - a background color is set and a border is set as below.

```
.PanelPadd    { background-color:#EFEFEF; border:solid #AAAAAA 1px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not show enough of your style code to analyze the problem. But I am assuming that you are setting a certain width to `FindCorrAddress` and `ClearCAddress`.

Because of minimal font-rendering differences, or rounding errors, or maybe even differences in the box model (are you running IE9 in Compatibility View?), a certain width that fits on one browser may not fit on another.

The best solution is to set no width at all, and to let the contents flow and define the width of the containers themselves.

Also, please remove the `<table>`. Using tables for layout is very bad style and asking for trouble.